# detached entity passed to persist error in Spring Boot when consuming a rest service

Tags: java, spring-boot

beginner here. I am trying to create 2 spring boot service applications that communicate with each other. One is called Speaker, other is called Review. The aim is to assign a review to each Speaker by doing something like speaker.setReview(review), and I retrieve this Review by making a GET request to the Review service using restTemplate.

I am able to retrieve a Review just fine using this code `Review review = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/review/get/1", Review.class);`

That works fine but the big issue is this line of code `hunchoJack.setReviews(review);` in this case, hunchoJack being our speaker. Trying this produces this huge error which I will shorten:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.jack.huncho.conference.model.Review`

What I want to do is simply be able to retrieve the Review from my review service and assign it to my speaker, hunchoJack, like so `hunchoJack.setReview(review)` but the error is getting in my way

What I already tried is by using the cascade annotation like so within the Speaker model

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
```

I have a lot of code to show, but I'm going to break it down a lot. The error occurs in my ConferenceApplication java file

ConferenceApplication.java

```
package...
imports...
main method...
restTemplate(RestTemplate builder) {...}
CommandLineRunner demo(SpeakerRepo repo, RestTemplate restTemplate) {

Review review = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/review/get/1",Review.class);
Review review2 = restTemplate.getForObject"http://localhost:8081/review/get/2",Review.class);

hunchoJack.setReview(review);
hunchojack.setReview(review2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your review objects are detached because they were obtained with the remote system's session. You will have to merge() these objects for them to be managed by your local session. In a microservice architecture you typically wouldn't be associating a review to a hunchjack. You would most likely be keeping a unique key to the review and ask the review service for the review by unique key when needed. If you choose not to do this then a review may be changed by your remote service by some other means and the review data you now have here is stale.